# Como alternar entre 2 folhas de estilo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Galera, possuo um site que toda a cor dele é em **dourado e preto**. 
Algumas cores de fonte em dourado, logo em dourado, barra lateral dourada, etc...

Como faço para, quando eu colocar um **botão** na lateral do meu site, escrito "versão roxa", e o visitante clicar neste botão, **mudar** esse `CSS` atual, e **substituir** por um novo `CSS` que terei criado, numa versão do site inteiro na cor "roxa".

Como se o site tivesse 2 estilos de cores, e o visitante pudesse escolher qual cor ele quer navegar no site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando do jquery `.attr("href")` com o comando `.on("click")` no botão, para alterar o link do seu css.

Veja um exemplo que fiz abaixo, onde criei dois links um para alterar o meu tema de dourado para roxo, e outro para alterar o tema para azul.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link id="temacss" href="temadourado.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="quadrado">Bla bla bla</div>

<a href="temaroxo.css" class="trocacssbtn">Trocar para Roxo</a>
<a href="temaazul.css" class="trocacssbtn">Trocar para Azul</a>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Ao pressionar qualquer link ou botão que contém
    // a class "trocacssbtn", executar a função.
    $(".trocacssbtn").on("click", function() {

    // Pega o atributo do link clicado para definir qual será o valor a ser trocado.
        var cssclass = $(this).attr("href"); 

       // Faz a troca do arquivo de css tema
       $("#temacss").attr("href", cssclass);

       // Retorna false para manter na mesma tela e finalizar a função.
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**temadourado.css**

```
div#quadrado {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #ff9600;
}
```

**temaroxo.css**

```
div#quadrado {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #783486;
}
```

**temaazul.css**

```
div#quadrado {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #072794;
}
```

Unica coisa que você precisa pensar depois é como você quer fixar isso. O usuário vai mudar ao clicar, mas se atualizar a página voltará tudo original.

Então você tem que ver na sua utilização, qual melhor maneira de atualizar e manter as alterações. Tem gente que utiliza cookies, outros salva as preferencias em banco de dados no cadastro do usuário. Ai é com você.

Comment: Bom, acredito que não precisaria fixar isso... Se atualizar, nao tem problema em voltar a cor original.
Só estou pensando uma coisa, meu site vai ser one page isso facilitaria muito, porém, ainda assim tem algumas paginas secundarias.
E quando eu clicasse no link pra acessar ela, tipo o botao "biografia", aí iria acessar com o fundo dourado ainda...
O que vc aconselharia eu fazer para quando eu clicar no botao do tema, ir o tema para todas as paginas (claro que, terei que criar um arquivo css para cada pagina do site)

Comment: Por exemplo se vc estiver usando PHP, vc pode salvar numa session a op escolhida pelo usuario e dai ao ir para as paginas secundarias carregar a op da session

Comment: E eu faria um pouco diferente do @Fernando VR eu n criaria 2 css, eu iria trabalhar com o jQuery fazendo 1 class adotar a cor a partida da escolha do usuário por exemplo uma class `$(.tema).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");` acredito q iria reduzir o codigo e ficaria menos trabalhaso caso vc queira colocar no futuro X cores

Comment: mas eu iria mudar o background image de umas divs, colors de algumas letras, ia dar muito trabalho... ainda assim prefiro a mudança de css completo

Comment: @LukasMonteiro, você vai usar html puro com javascript ou vai usar em php também?? Se usar o php facilita muito, pq vc pode setar o cookie em javascript quando trocar o tema pelo jquery (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) e recuperar via php em todas as páginas colocando algo do tipo: `<link id="temacss" href="<?php echo (!empty($_COOKIE["meutema"])) ? $_COOKIE["meutema"] : 'temadourado.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> `

Comment: ainda nao coloquei nenhum php do site, mas terei que colocar pq na sessão "contato" terá um formulario para ser enviado ao meu email. 
O site que estou criando não terá uma sessão "cadastro de clientes" ou algo do tipo
Nunca mexi com php.

Comment: Caso não utilze php, e vc queira tudo em html puro. Você deve setar o cookie com javascript ao alterar o tema, mas quando mudar de pagina ao terminar de carrega-la, deverá puxar o cookie e fazer a alteração novamente com o cookie q foi setado. O q na minha opinião é ruim, pq a pagina vai dar aquela piscada toda vez, mostrando as cores originais e mudando de cor ao carregar a pagina inteira. Com php vc ja carrega direto no tema escolhido.

Comment: Tenta aprender um pouco de php, você vai gostar muito, e vai facilitar bastante sua vida.  Aqui tem um link sobre cookies em php: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Eu estava pensando o seguinte: É possível com um botão que eu clicar lá no canto superior do meu site atualizar a página e entrar um novo HTML + CSS? 
Pq aí no novo html que entraria eu colocava os links dos menus direcionando para a página já formatada com a cor do tema.

Comment: Tem milhares de maneiras de fazer. Nesse esquema q vc diz, daria pra ser por pasta. Por exemplo: `www.seusite.com.br/index.html` -> tema padrão. E quando mudar de tema ir para outra pasta do tipo: ` ``www.seusite.com.br/temaroxo/index.html``. Mas não aconselho, pq vc vai ter muito mais trabalho, se a sua ideia é mudar apenas o css. Se fururamente vc querer mudar algum texto no html vai ter q fazer a alteração em todas as pastas q criou. O q vai te dar muito trabalho. Você resolveria tudo isso facilmente com PHP.

Comment: Acho que terei que fazer este metodo mais trabalhoso, pq tecnicamente eu nao teria que mudar só o css, já que a logo que eu coloquei no meu site tá pelo html como uma < img >, aí mudaria da imagem "dourada" pra imagem "roxa"

Comment: Ainda sim vc resolveria fácil com php, na mesma pegada do que mencionei acima: `<img src="<?php echo (!empty($_COOKIE["meutema"])) ? $_COOKIE["meutema"].'logo.jpg' : 'temadouradologo.jpg'; ?>" />`. Da uma pesquisada em php amigo. Vc vai ver que vai salvar sua vida kkk